# Updating my .htaccess file using Yoast SEO plugin stopped my wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I inserted a image expiry code in the .htaccess file in my website using Yoast SEO plugin caused the whole website showing internal server error 500.

The existing code before updateing the .htaccess file was:

```html
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The updated code was:

```html
 # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    # END WordPress

<If Modulemod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On 
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

1. Is it caused due to not providing space in the  line or using it two times.
2. .htaccess file does not showing the updated code.
3. The admin panel stopped working.
4. Updating through ftp panel does not resolving the issue.
5. Deactivating the plugins also not working.
   my site is securedoc.org

Answer (score 0):

The specific .htaccess rules are not related to Yoast, so how come you make the relation between the two? There is an error though in your IF command.

`<IfModule mod_expires.c>`

You are missing a space there.